# How to use XML/XElement to get a colon : into the first part of the tag...?

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

I am trying to create an XML document.

I need the document to display ike this...

```
<HART:HART xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:HART="www.myurlhere.com" xsi:schemaLocation="www.myurlhere">
```

This is the code i am using

```
        public FileStreamResult Submission(Models.Reporting.SubmissionViewModel svm)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();

        xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        xws.Indent = true;

        XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.myurlhere.com");
        XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        XNamespace schemaLocation = XNamespace.Get("http://www.myurlhere.com");

        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, xws))
        {
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(

                new XElement(xmlns + "HART",
                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
                    new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation)


            ));
            doc.WriteTo(xw);
        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        return File(ms, "text/xml", "Sample.xml");
    }
```

However it displays like this

```
<HART xmlns="http://www.myurlhere.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myurlhere.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

> As you can see the first part is just HART not HART:HART

I have never done this before so any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is exactly equivalent. `xmlns="http://www.myurlhere.com"` sets the default namespace so `<HART>` is interpreted to be in this namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the part before the : is just a placeholder to shorten the namespace. This is mostly used as you need to use more than one namespace.

by specifying the namespace on the element level als xmlns= all the childs below will have this namespace until you specify again a child with a xmlns=

if you insist on having `<HART:HART xmlns:HART="">` you can do this

```
new XElement(xmlns + "HART", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "HART", xmlns)          ));
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt really have an understanding of this, but i do now.